# How to get the checked values from a checkbox in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

A dynamic checkbox is created from the list of cartoonData. On selecting each cartoon in a checkbox, I need to read the values in typescript function.

```
In HTML  File

<div *ngFor="let cartoon of cartoonsData">
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)" />
    <label for="checkbox" >{{ cartoon.name }}</label>
</div>
```

```
In Typescript file

onChange(event){
//Code to get the checked values
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add a reference on the input such as `#checkbox`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let cartoon of cartoonsData">
    <input #checkbox type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)" />
    <label for="checkbox" >{{ cartoon.name }}</label>
</div>
```

Next use `@ViewChildren()` to reference the template reference. Then wherever you need to access the checked items you can use a `filter` on the elements. You could also convert this to its own function if you need to use it often.

```js
@Component()
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChildren('checkbox') checkboxes!: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>>;

  onChange(event){
    // To get the elements
    const checkedItems = this.checkboxes.filter(box => box.nativeElement.checked);

    // To get the actual values instead of just the element
    // const checkedItems = this.cartoonsData.filter((x,index)=>this.checkboxes.find((c,i)=>i==index).nativeElement.checked).map(x=>x.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I do see ElementRef but I don't get the exact value. For example, if the checkbox options are checked as Pokemon, I do see a ElementRef for that but not the value. I tried displaying it on the console.

Comment: You need to add `value` to the checkbox input item or bind to `ngModel`

Comment: I feel that should be: `const checkedItems = this.cartoonsData.filter((x,index)=>this.checkboxes.find((c,i)=>i==index).nativeElement.checked).map(x=>x.name)` [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-31yzp8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Yeah, that works too if you want to get the actual data.

Comment: Cartoondata is hardcoded in typescript. But since my checkbox are going to be dynamic(i.e., checkbox fields are fetched from db and distplayed), how do I do get the values?

Comment: @Badri, it's the same. I add an answer to see how use with an async pipe

Answer (score 1):

If we want an array with the "value"

```
  cartoonsData=[{name:'one'},{name:'two'},{name:'three'}]
  result:any=[]
  @ViewChildren('checkbox') checkboxes!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  onChange(event){
    const checkedItems = this.cartoonsData.filter((x,index)=>
                  this.checkboxes.find((c,i)=>i==index).nativeElement.checked)
                 .map(x=>x.name)
    this.result=checkedItems;
  }
```

If the data goes from a service we can subscribe in ngOnInit (but don't forget unsubscribe)

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.subscription=this.dataService.getData().subscribe((res:any[])=>{
       this.cartoonsData=res;
   })
}
ngOnDestroy()
{
   this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

Another option is use pipe async, but we need store in an array the result of the observable. So we can define an observable like

```
obs$=this.service.getData().pipe(tap((res:any)=>this.cartoonsData=res))
```

And use in .html

```
<div *ngFor="let cartoon of obs$|async">
   ...
</div>
```

There'e no problem because the "pipe(tap)" fill our auxiliar variable. see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vtye8a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). (instead create a service simply I create an object with the property getData())